# Strange data file in /

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, filesystem

I have got a strange data file in my / directory for some months. It's named `tmpUGy0UNqBDAN8BRg_iwbGcvv6S .w62on1kHPb4UtBeezebArfjiGrbJLSdyO6MX7tz_qUyFLz53UZaMWRN lpdzIu2UE.x60v9p.Cn76hktF6QUZGOGZjz7NVBK8_Evh1dx4SscgBeLo5TtXqErwZWC7ma9QvACMaKLoI2 y5d7urc3LsKrUk4zoPjrL71aMEWfCXWMdqJ8YQUgVh1vdPYLhkA-0I-lga5zSe7eIaSZS8bm0Xdm8tV2N 1z` .
It's owned by root. `less` says its a binary file. Here's the `ls` and `file` output.

```
$ ls -l /
total 40476
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 May 28 12:21 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root     4096 May 28 12:23 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 May 27  2014 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root     4140 Jun  8 14:59 dev
drwxr-xr-x 153 root root    12288 Jun  8 15:05 etc
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root     4096 Mar 21 14:42 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       33 Apr 14 16:05 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       33 Apr  1 19:18 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root     4096 Mar 16 15:16 lib
drwx------   2 root root    16384 May 27  2014 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root     4096 May 19 17:08 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Apr 19  2012 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root     4096 Apr 15 18:19 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 180 root root        0 Jun  8 14:59 proc
drwx------  16 root root     4096 May 24 13:29 root
drwxr-xr-x  29 root root      960 Jun  8 15:05 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    12288 May 28 12:19 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Aug 20  2013 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root        0 Jun  8 14:59 sys
drwxrwxrwt   5 root root     4096 Jun  8 15:09 tmp
-rw-------   1 root root 41352585 Dec 30 20:49 tmpUGy0UNqBDAN8BRg_iwbGcvv6S .w62on1kHPb4UtBeezebArfjiGrbJLSdyO6MX7tz_qUyFLz53UZaMWRN lpdzIu2UE.x60v9p.Cn76hktF6QUZGOGZjz7NVBK8_Evh1dx4SscgBeLo5TtXqErwZWC7ma9QvACMaKLoI2 y5d7urc3LsKrUk4zoPjrL71aMEWfCXWMdqJ8YQUgVh1vdPYLhkA-0I-lga5zSe7eIaSZS8bm0Xdm8tV2N 1z
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root     4096 May  7 18:09 usr
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root     4096 Sep 29  2014 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       30 Apr 14 16:05 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       30 Apr  1 19:18 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic


$ sudo file /tmpUGy0UNqBDAN8BRg_iwbGcvv6S\ .w62on1kHPb4UtBeezebArfjiGrbJLSdyO6MX7tz_qUyFLz53UZaMWRN\ lpdzIu2UE.x60v9p.Cn76hktF6QUZGOGZjz7NVBK8_Evh1dx4SscgBeLo5TtXqErwZWC7ma9QvACMaKLoI2\ y5d7urc3LsKrUk4zoPjrL71aMEWfCXWMdqJ8YQUgVh1vdPYLhkA-0I-lga5zSe7eIaSZS8bm0Xdm8tV2N\ 1z 
/tmpUGy0UNqBDAN8BRg_iwbGcvv6S .w62on1kHPb4UtBeezebArfjiGrbJLSdyO6MX7tz_qUyFLz53UZaMWRN lpdzIu2UE.x60v9p.Cn76hktF6QUZGOGZjz7NVBK8_Evh1dx4SscgBeLo5TtXqErwZWC7ma9QvACMaKLoI2 y5d7urc3LsKrUk4zoPjrL71aMEWfCXWMdqJ8YQUgVh1vdPYLhkA-0I-lga5zSe7eIaSZS8bm0Xdm8tV2N 1z: data
```

Lubuntu 14.04

Comment: you can always try doing ` sudo hexdump -C filename | less ` to see its contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like someone forgot to add a "/" to some parameter: the files start with `/tmp` so I would assume for now that is the directory "/tmp").

Besides that: files like this in `/tmp` are normal and are temporary files for instance to track user sessions.

- December 30th is a long time ago so I doubt you still know what you installed back then. "bleachbit" uses these kind of file names but that is a longshot.
- Check the contents of the file with "cat -v"  and see if you can track down the name of the software that made them.

Comment: Thanks @rinzwind, the file is binary and I can't make any sense of the contents (It's just filled with '@^'s in a single line) even in UXTERM.

Comment: Pity. Sometimes there are some clues in there (even it its a binairy). I would suggest to remove it and periodically check if one comes back.